# why cufftplan3d takes a lot of time

Tags: cuda, cufft

I have two questions to ask
why the API `cufftPlan3d(plan, nx,ny,nz,c2c)` takes  around 300 milliseconds to execute?

is it a gpu operation or cpu operation?

Can anybody give me an explanation in detail. I could not find a good explanation anywhere.

Comment: Is this the first GPU (i.e. cufft, CUDA) call in your application?  If not, is it the first cufft call?  If you perform cufftPlan3d more than once, are the subsequent calls also taking 300 milliseconds?  This is perhaps just an artifact of CUDA or cufft initialization - impacting the first call only.  An ordinary cufft planning operation makes GPU memory allocations under the hood, so it involves both CPU activity and GPU activity (unless you take control of the memory allocations yourself within cufft.)

Comment: Yeah , am using cufftplan3d only once in my application . However for the second time cufftplan3d call will not take time?

Comment: The first cufft call and the first cuda call in your application are likely to incur additional start-up overheads.  Subsequent calls are usually shorter.

Comment: thanks robert for the help